# Limited GraphicsMagick error while displaying image

Tags: image, matlab, octave

I am trying to show an image with following code:

```
filename = 'testflower.png';
A = importdata(filename);
image(A);
```

However, I am getting following errors:

```
$ octave showimg.m 
warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 16 bits per pixel
warning: called from
    imformats>default_formats at line 256 column 11
    imformats at line 79 column 3
    imageIO at line 106 column 11
    imread at line 106 column 30
    importdata at line 110 column 50
    showimg.m at line 3 column 3
error: invalid value for array property "cdata"
error: called from
    image>__img__ at line 201 column 5
    image at line 119 column 10
    showimg.m at line 4 column 1
```

I am working on Octave version 4.0.3-3 on Debian Stable Linux.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Edit: Details of the png (as suggested by @MarkSetchell in comments) are as follows:

```
$ pngcheck -v testflower.png 
File: testflower.png (17349 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    927 x 258 image, 8-bit palette, non-interlaced
  chunk PLTE at offset 0x00025, length 768: 256 palette entries
  chunk tRNS at offset 0x00331, length 217: 217 transparency entries
  chunk pHYs at offset 0x00416, length 9: 3780x3780 pixels/meter (96 dpi)
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x0042b, length 8192
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, default compression
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x02437, length 8058
  chunk IEND at offset 0x043bd, length 0
No errors detected in testflower.png (7 chunks, 92.7% compression).
```

Comment: Try checking your image either with `pngcheck -v testflower.png` or with `gm identify -verbose testflower.png` and pasting the output into your question. A `gm identify -version` would maybe help too.

Comment: Pl see edit in my question above. What does this information mean?

Comment: Just a hunch that it may be an issue understanding a palettised image. If you have ImageMagick installed (as well as GraphicsMagick) you could try converting it to an RGB888 image instead of a palette image with `convert testflower.png PNG24:flower.png` and see if it can load that.

Comment: If you only have problems with one special png you should upload it and add a link. Other pngs and jpegs with `img = imread("foo.png");` work fine, right?

Comment: `A = imread(filename); ` works! But why `A = importdata(filename);` does not work?

Comment: @MarkSetchell : Yes, image shows properly after `$ convert testflower.png PNG24:flower.png` ! What does this mean?

Comment: I don't use R myself - I can only suggest that, either R or GraphicsMagick, has some issues with palletised PNG images. Hopefully someone more familiar with R will be able to dig deeper now we have an idea what the issue may be. Sorry I can't be of any further help.

Comment: How is `R` involved in this? I am using `Gnu Octave` which is a `Matlab` compatible language. `R` is completely different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)

Comment: Sorry, I meant Octave where I wrote R - like I said, I only know the imaging side of it not the mathsy/sciency/statistics side.

Comment: @rnso: You can step through the code and debug this why imread works and importdata not. I would guess, that importdata calls imread under the hood. Lerning how to debug inside octave is very important and will save you hours of fustration. In your case `debug_on_error(1)` then run it, then `dbstack`, `dblist`, `dbup` and so on. You can always watch variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can savely ignore the warning because the 16bits, [see here](https://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick).

The error you see is from image (not importdata), apparently because the return value of `importdata` isn't compatible with `image` in your GNU Octave version (it works with 5.x)

Use

```
img = imread ("test.png");
image (img)
```

instead

Comment: It will be great if you can briefly post here how to use debug commands.